# Scrolling several blocks with timeout function

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

I have a small problem when scrolling blocks with a specified interval of time.

The fact is that when a function in one direction, for example, skrolDovn calculation occurs correct and blocks behave as required. 
But the reverse scrolling their calculations are lost and can not determine what is the reason

I'm reading many posts but not seen this problem

```
function AnimateScrollBlocks(elem){

        var elemScroll = parseInt(elem.offset().top) - $(window).scrollTop();

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            elem.stop(true).animate({'margin-top': elemScroll},3000);
        }, 1000);
    }

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        AnimateScrollBlocks($('.pizza-bg'));
        AnimateScrollBlocks($('.rols-bg'));
        AnimateScrollBlocks($('.vegies-bg'));
        AnimateScrollBlocks($('.beer-bg'));
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Almag13/xsm0w8g4/

Comment: You say "skrolDovn calculation occurs correct and blocks behave as required."  What is the expected behavior? Could you please add some more details. But I appreciate that you have added the jsfiddle

Comment: If we are to scroll down calculation behavior occurs right blocks, but to scroll back, the blocks do not fall into place
Sorry ScrollDown

Comment: Your blocks have some initial positions (let's call them a,b,c,d). If I scroll x pixels downwards (your blocks scroll further upwards, with respect to the page, which according to you is expected behavior). Now, when I scroll upwards by the same amount, i.e. x pixels, after the expected amount of scrolling, do you want the blocks to come back to the starting position (i.e. a,b,c,d)?

Comment: Yes, but I do not know for what reason they will not be returned

Comment: Are you sure that what is currently happening when scrolling is done downwards, is your expected behavior? Because if I scroll downwards and stop, the blocks move upward. Then when I further scroll down, stop and repeat this, the blocks ultimately leave the window (margin-top becomes negative). Check the console output in this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xsm0w8g4/2/  So, I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: how i think,
we have a block, we value scrollTop scrolls on the browser window.
ScrollTop browser window may be different: negative and positive.
With a negative value to scroll block moves for 2 seconds to scroll up to the specified, and if positive at the same height down.
But now this is not happening ... Although the console.log is clear that it must?